# Spivak Chap 1, 12(v) A somewhat different question.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove $ \left| x \right| - \left| y \right| \leq \left| x-y \right|$ Now, Spivak cryptically adds

> (A very short proof is possible if you write things in the right way).

Now, that is the part I want to understand.

So, his answer says

> It follows from (iv)....

So (iv) is pretty straight forward (I think).

Prove $ \left| x-y \right| \leq \left| x \right| + \left| y\right|$ which is a variation of Theorem 1  ie

> for any numbers $a$ and $b$ we have $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ hence Spivak's proof: $|x - y| = |x + (-y)| \leq |x| + |-y| = |x| + |y| $

...  Now, can someone help me understand how Spivak's answer 'follows from (iv)' ie $$\left| x \right| = \left|  y - (y-x) \right| \leq \left| y \right| + \left| y - x \right|$$ hence  $\left| x \right| - \left| y\right| \leq \left| x - y \right|$

I think the conclusion is pretty straight forward... it's the part before that I am trying to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would do it slightly differently.

Note that $x = x + (-y+y) = (x-y) + y$, so
$$|x| = |(x-y)+y| \le |x-y| + |y|.$$
Now subtract $|y|$ from both sides.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.  May I ask you to weigh in on why this would be related to his previous proof?

Comment: He wrote $x = y - (y-x)$ instead. In all my years of assigning this exercise, I never noticed his clunky advice. Much more natural to do it directly from the usual triangle inequality.

Comment: Can’t say I disagree. Thank you. I should have asked earlier. I’ve been mulling about this for 2 days now. :-)